# Postgres unique constraint on index does not work

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, unique-constraint

On a quite simple table

```
CREATE TABLE collectionmaster
(
  id character varying(32) NOT NULL,
  version integer,
  publisherid character varying(12),
  title character varying(1024),
  subtitle character varying(1024),
  type character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT collectionmaster_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
CREATE INDEX idx_coll_title
  ON collectionmaster
  USING btree
  (title COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

I tried to add a unique check either via unique index

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_uni_coll_title
  ON collectionmaster
  USING btree
  (publisherid COLLATE pg_catalog."default", title COLLATE pg_catalog."default", (COALESCE(subtitle, 'no_sub'::character varying)) COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

or via unique constraint

```
ALTER TABLE collectionmaster
  ADD CONSTRAINT uni_coll_title UNIQUE(publisherid, title, subtitle);
```

to intercept accidentally multiple creation by a java service (spring-jpa on hibernate) executed in several threads. But strangely neither of index and constraint works as expected. Eight records are added by eight threads which are not unique according to either constraint or index in separate transaction, but no unique violations are thrown, and all records are inserted into the table. And none of the values are null, as was the problem in other questions here.
The constaint was not deferred, index as constraint where valid.
Postgres version is 9.2.

I am quite clueless here.

EDIT: These are the results of a query in this table, extracted from pgAdmin (hard to format it nicer here):

```
"id";"version";"publisherid";"title";"subtitle";"type"
"53b3df625baf40bf885b48daa366fbc8";1;"5109138";"Titel";"Untertitel";"set"
"2673ef9a33f84289995d6f7288f07b46";1;"5109138";"Titel";"Untertitel";"set"
"ef7c385205034fdc89fe39e3eca48408";1;"5109138";"Titel";"Untertitel";"set"
"527922f2f3464f91826dbae2e2b67caf";1;"5109138";"Titel";"Untertitel";"set"
"794638a725324319852d10b828257df7";1;"5109138";"Titel";"Untertitel";"set"
"dbe2201058974d63a2107131f0080233";1;"5109138";"Titel";"Untertitel";"set"
"cbb77c7c1adb415db006853a6f6244ac";1;"5109138";"Titel";"Untertitel";"set"
"0b6606fe015040fbbc85444361ab414c";1;"5109138";"Titel";"Untertitel";"set"
```

Even on these I can execute

```
insert into collectionmaster(id, version, publisherid, title, subtitle, type) values('aaa',1,'5109138','Titel','Untertitel','set')
```

without getting a constraint violation. I can't believe it, too, but this is the problem...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes I am; the values in the columns are identical in every respect, coming from the same java data object.

Comment: Then please show us some sample data (ideally as `INSERT` statements) that reproduce this problem. Given the information you have shown this is very hard to believe.

Comment: Could be trailing whitespace. Please show us some data.

Comment: Hard to believe that a unique constraint doesn't work, but there is also something else: Your unique index and unique constraint aren't the same. But whatever uniques you want, both work fine.

Comment: Works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/999d4/1 are you sure you created the index on the same database where you run the insert?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, in the same pgAdmin SQL window. And even stranger is: when I drop the constraint, and try to recreate it on the non-unique data, I get the expected error message that data prevents creation.

Comment: Are you sure your spring-jpa does not want to "fix" your schema at initialization? Like, with `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` is set to `update` or `create-drop`? http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html I'm not sure `update` can drop unwanted indexes too, but could you double-check this with pgAdmin (after you started your application)?

Comment: @pozs Oh my god, that's it! Hibernate recreated the table without the index or constraint! I was completely on the wrong way. Please post this as an answer so that I can reward you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your spring-jpa config [`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html) is not set to `create-drop`.

That way, hibernate will always drop & re-create your whole schema, which won't contain your custom unique constraints, nor your indexes.