# Generation of duplicate unique constraint names

Tags: postgresql, grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

when defining a unique constraint for a domain class, grails generates for the database a constraint-name which is based on the property name.
When using Postgres as a database the name will be 'unique_language' for the following constraint definition.

```
   static constraints = {
      language nullable: false, unique: 'product'
   }
```

When I now have a second domain class which has also a unique constraint on a property with the same name, grails will again create a database constraint with the name 'unique_language'. 
The problem is, that for Postgres the name for a unique constraint must also be unique for the database schema. This means in our case that the second 
constraint is not applied to the database.

Is there a way to customize or define the unique index names?

I was looking if it is possible to enhance the NamingStrategy, but I couldn't find a point where to do the changes.

We are currently using grails 2.4.4

Comment: this may give you a clue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35220475/spring-boot-hibernate-grails-ignores-ddlauto-in-yml-file  issue discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168611/postgres-unique-constraint-on-index-does-not-work

Comment: @vahid: I don't think this is the same issue. Here the problem is that the names of unique constraints must be unique for the entire database but grails or hibernate just creates the key like this: `unique_propertyname`. This obviously fails when you have multiple domain classes with properties that are named the same and that all have unique constrains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed in Grails 3.1.0.RC2: https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues/623

Answer (score 1):

We are using in our case grails 2.4.4 and therefore now implemented a workaround.

We implemented a new dialect which inherits from the class `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect`.

The only change in the new dialect class is the assignment of a custom UnitqueDelegate called `PostgresUniqueDelegate`. This class inherits from the `org.hibernate.dialect.unique.DefaultUniqueDelegate` and overwrites the methods for the constraints generation.

```
class PostgresSQL9DialectUniqueConstraints extends PostgreSQL9Dialect {

    private final UniqueDelegate uniqueDelegate

    PostgresSQL9DialectUniqueConstraints() {
        super()
        uniqueDelegate = new PostgresUniqueDelegate(this)
    }

    @Override
    UniqueDelegate getUniqueDelegate() {
        return uniqueDelegate
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you also post the code for PostgresUniqueDelegate?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for the PostgresUniqueDelegate class

```
class PostgresUniqueDelegate extends DefaultUniqueDelegate {

    PostgresUniqueDelegate(Dialect dialect) {
        super(dialect)
    }

    private final PREFIX = "unique_"

    private String getCustomUniqueKey(String uniqueKeyName, String tableName) {
        return uniqueKeyName.replaceAll(PREFIX, PREFIX + tableName + "_")
    }

    @Override
    String getAlterTableToAddUniqueKeyCommand(
            org.hibernate.mapping.UniqueKey uniqueKey,
            String defaultCatalog,
            String defaultSchema)
    {
        // Do this here, rather than allowing UniqueKey/Constraint to do it.
        // We need full, simplified control over whether or not it happens.
        final String tableName = uniqueKey.getTable().getQualifiedName(dialect, defaultCatalog, defaultSchema)
        final String constraintName = dialect.quote(getCustomUniqueKey(uniqueKey.getName(), tableName))
        return "alter table " + tableName + " add constraint " + constraintName + " " + uniqueConstraintSql(uniqueKey)
    }

    @Override
    String getAlterTableToAddUniqueKeyCommand(UniqueKey uniqueKey) {
        // Do this here, rather than allowing UniqueKey/Constraint to do it.
        // We need full, simplified control over whether or not it happens.
        final String tableName = uniqueKey.getTable().getQualifiedName(dialect)
        final String constraintName = dialect.quote(getCustomUniqueKey(uniqueKey.getName(), tableName))

        return "alter table " + tableName + " add constraint " + constraintName + uniqueConstraintSql(uniqueKey);
    }

}
```